# PHP - MailHandler.php header location not working from here

Tags: php

I am using TMForm.js to execute `bat/MailHandler.php` file to validate username and password for a login form. I am using Firefox Firebug to check the request and response for `bat/MailHandler.php` and that is works fine, it checks the database verifies the username and password but fails to transfer back the control to after login page using `location` header as shown in the code below. Header location is not working in my `bat/MailHandler.php` file. I am pasting the code here, please do guide me with the solution.

```
<?php
     include("../connect.php");

     $userName=$_POST['name'];
     $password=$_POST['state'];
     //$value=$_POST['check'];

     $sql="SELECT * from login where email='".$userName."'";

     $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
     while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
         $memID=$row['id'];
         $userNamedb=$row['email'];
         $passworddb=$row['password'];
     }

    if($userName==$userNamedb && $password==$passworddb){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['id']= $memID;
        $_SESSION['uname']= $userName;
        $_SESSION['upassword']= $password;
        header("location:../afterlogin.php");
    }
    else{
        $flag=1;
        header("location:../memberlogin.php?valid=".$flag);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to Location: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

The link above also has an example how to modify your code.

---

Side notes:

1.

```
$userName=$_POST['name'];
// ...
$sql="SELECT * from login where email='".$userName."'";
```

Don't do this. This code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. See also:

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
- https://xkcd.com/327/

2.

Do not use `mysql_*` functions. Use `mysqli_*` instead:

> It is not recommended to use the old mysql extension for new development, as it has been deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 and will be removed in the future.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php